# Returning and storing a variable calculated in python script that is run from Perl script

Tags: python-3.x, perl

I run a simple .py script from a Perl script.
Here is the python code (TmRD.py):

```
import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqUtils import MeltingTemp as mt
def calculate_tm (seq):
    seq_Tm = mt.Tm_NN(seq, nn_table = mt.R_DNA_NN1)
    return seq_Tm
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = str(sys.argv[1])
    myseq = Seq(s)
    tm = calculate_tm(myseq)
```

I would like to return and store the tm parameter ,calculated in the python script, in the Perl script.
Here is the Perl script (test.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $arg1 = $ARGV[0];
print "ARG 1: $arg1\n";
my $ret = `/home/tmp/TmRD.py $arg1`;
print "ret $ret\n";
```

I Run it from the console as following:

```
perl /home/tmp/test.pl auucuucgcgga
```

So the expected output should be :

```
ret 30.014854619578273
```

However the output that I get is :

```
ret
```

Comment: What do you get if you run from the shell: `/home/tmp/TmRD.py auucuucgcgga` ?

Comment: Repost of [earlier closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566213/run-python-script-from-perl-script-and-storing-the-returned-value-in-the-perl-c). Why not improve that one to get it re-opened instead? Oh, and same questions as in my comment on that one.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add print(tm) to the end of your python file

```
import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqUtils import MeltingTemp as mt
def calculate_tm (seq):
    seq_Tm = mt.Tm_NN(seq, nn_table = mt.R_DNA_NN1)
    return seq_Tm
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = str(sys.argv[1])
    myseq = Seq(s)
    tm = calculate_tm(myseq)
    print(tm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this goal is use the inline::python module from cpan, this way you don't have to call python from perl so to speak but have your perl directly call python and pass the variables that way.
https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Python

In your case (I did not try this) it would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Inline Python => <<END;
import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqUtils import MeltingTemp as mt
def calculate_tm (seq):
    seq_Tm = mt.Tm_NN(seq, nn_table = mt.R_DNA_NN1)
    return seq_Tm
END
my $arg1 = $ARGV[0];
print "ARG 1: $arg1\n";
my $ret = calculate_tm($arg1);
print "ret $ret\n";
```